Cogsci account disappeared
I was using the stack exchange and my account on cogsci was deleted all the questions and answers transferred to another account and my rep lost. I guess it's an account glitch?

Gonna need some more details here. Can you link to a question of yours on CogSci?

Yes its hard in the app this is a question edit and answer made by me cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/8545/logical-skills-and-mathemtical-skills-of-people-with-adhd

My answer on memory biased positive and negative was deleted

Looks like your account was removed by a moderator. I'll migrate the question here over to the cogsci meta so they can weigh in there.

Just to let you know that I've seen your post, but I don't have any specific information about this perhaps one of the other moderators will know more.

@JeromyAnglim thank you for the comment i'm sure someone just pressed the wrong button while they were on vacation

@AnnaLear so they responded could you comment?

Your account was deleted since it was created with the intention of avoiding a suspension.

how do i need to prove my identity?

Convo about this on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243499/cogsci-deleting-my-account
